# Beautifulsoup findAll, how to get the second text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, findall

I am doing some python work and couldn´t find the answer to this question so hoping someone could help. 
I am using findAll in python and getting the output of two numbers in text form. however I only want the second number and not the first. How do I target the second number?

This is my code:

```
product_price_container_after = container.findAll("div",{"class":"discounted"})
product_price_after = product_price_container_after[0].text
print(product_price_after)
```

This is where I am trying to get it from:

```
<div class="col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow">
<span style="color: #888888;"><strike>59,98€</strike></span><br/>19,99€
                                        </div>
```

So the output is:

59,98€19,99€

How do I only get 19,99€ ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a public url available?

Comment: It is taken from steams page: https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) or [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) methods to remove elements from the tree.

```
discountedDivs = container.findAll("div", {"class": "discounted"})

for discountedDiv in discountedDivs:
    discountedDiv.find("span").extract()
    print(discountedDiv.text) ## returns 19,99€
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked! Now I have to figure out all my other problems, but this was the biggest one so thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I can't reproduce your code, its incomplete.
Try this though:

```
product_price_after = product_price_container_after[1].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use stripped strings

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=1')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
prices = soup.select('.discounted')

for price in prices:
    if price.text is not None:
        strings = [string for string in price.stripped_strings]
        print(strings[1])
```

Or next_sibling:

```
for price in prices:
    if price.text is not None:
        print(price.find('br').next_sibling)
```